# Auto-complete With Async Data not working properly

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to add the ability to search by number after I push some data to an Observable (courses$).

The auto complete isn't working properly. For example when I type `55`, the numbers `33` and `44` are still showing.
What I'm doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
Search
<input type="text" [formControl]="search">

<div *ngIf="(courses$ | async) as courses">
  <pre>{{ courses | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = "CodeSandbox";
    courses$: Observable<any>;
    search: FormControl = new FormControl();
    constructor() {
        this.courses$ = this.getCourses$();
    }

    public getCourses$(){
        return of([
            '11',
            '22'
        ]);
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        //this.courses$ = this.getCourses$();
        this.courses$ = this.search
            .valueChanges
            .pipe(
                startWith(''),
                switchMap(value => {
                    if(value == ''){
                        return this.getCourses$();
                    }
                    
                    return this.courses$
                        .pipe(                
                            map((result: any) => {
                                let newData = [];
                    
                                result.forEach((data) => {
                                    if((data.toLowerCase()).includes(value.toLowerCase())){
                                        newData.push(data)
                                    }
                                });
                                
                                result = newData;
                                return result;
                            })
                        )                   
                })
            );
            
        this.courses$ = this.courses$
            .pipe(
                map(value => {
                    value.push('33');
                    value.push('44');
                    return value;
                })
            );      
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assigning `this.courses$` variable twice. And the last assignment pushes the value `33` and `44` to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    ngOnInit(){
      this.courses$ = this.getCourses$().pipe(
        switchMap(courses => this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(searchValue => serachValue.toLowerCase()),
          map(searchValue => courses.filter(course => course.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)))
        )),
      );
    }
```

first we get all the courses (we don't want to make a call to back-end every time search value changes), and then filter them based on the search value.

The route cause of your behavior was already explained by @michael-d in the comment: You're assigning this.courses$ variable twice. And the last assignment pushes the value 33 and 44 to it.